# Advanced Firewall Exceptions in batch (any direction)

Tags: windows, exception, batch-file, cmd, firewall

I am using this code to add the software "example.exe" to the exception list:

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule action=allow profile=any protocol=any enable=yes direction=in name=example_in program = "C:\\Program Files\\example.exe" > NUL
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule action=allow profile=any protocol=any enable=yes direction=out name=example_out program = "C:\\Program Files\\example.exe" > NUL
```

How can I do the "in|out" part in one only line?

I mean something like:

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule action=allow profile=any protocol=any enable=yes direction=any name=example_in program = "C:\\Program Files\\example.exe" > NUL
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do this with a quicky batch file like:

```
for %%x in (in out) do (
    netsh advfirewall firewall add rule action=allow profile=any protocol=any enable=yes direction=%%x name=example_%%x program = "C:\\Program Files\\example.exe" > NUL
)
```

Comment: thanks, this is good, but it doesn't really exist any "any" for the direction argument? :S

Comment: According to the help, no: 

`netsh advfirewall firewall add rule ?`